# Restore object from AWS Glacier to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have configured life cycle policy in S3, some of objects in S3 are stored in Glacier class, some of object are still in S3, now I am trying to restore objects from Glacier, I can get object list in S3 by java AWS SDK, how can I know which object is in Glacier storage by AWS SDK? The reason is when I try restore an object not in Glacier, I will have a exception. I wanna avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ListObjects` Amazon S3 API call can be used to obtain a list of objects in a given bucket.

The list of files returned includes a `StorageClass` field. It can be one of:

- STANDARD
- REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
- GLACIER

The `GLACIER` storage class indicates that the *contents* of the object is currently in Glacier.

Answer (score 0):

Restore Data from AWS Glacier to S3 Bucket:

1. Connect to any AWS EC2 Instance
2. Install S3CMD on EC2
3. s3cmd restore --restore-days=10 --recursive s3://bucketName/

Note : restore-days=10 --->Data will be available for next 10 days after it will return back to Glacier.